# Paypal payment without cvc

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I need to implement a an hardware where a user put a Credit Card, it pay 1$, and it gets a service.
The credit card reader is attached on a computer, so the payment will be made by an application.
I want to implement a payment with paypal.
I need to make the payment only reading the credit card, without asking user nothing (name, expire date, cvc, etc...).

Anyone knows if PayPal can do this?
Thanks!
Claudio

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options out there.

You can get setup with PayPal Payments Pro and integrate with a Point Of Sale solution.

Another option is get setup with PayPal Here and either integrate with an iPad, iPhone, Android or a Point Of Sale Solution. Please Note, PayPal Here is not offered in every country, here is the link with the information on it:

[PayPal Here Information](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader)

Here is some information on Partners with PayPal Here:
[PayPal Here Partners](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/accept-payments-in-store)

Another option with PayPal Payments Pro and Virtual Terminal you can add a Magtek Card Reader to your Laptop or PC and download a specific software that will integrate with PayPal Payments Pro and Magtek.

Here is the link to Magtek, keep in mind that PayPal does not offer any technical support for this software. It does integrate with PayPal Payments Pro Virtual Terminal:

[Magtek Software Virtual Terminal Integration](http://www.magensa.net/installs/ocx.aspx)

Here is the PayPal Full Partner Directory to help you find a solution:
[Full PayPal Partner Directory](https://www.paypal-marketing.com/paypal/html/hosted/emarketing/partner/directory/v2/)

Answer (score 0):

[USBSwiper](http://www.usbswiper.com/PayPal-Point-of-Sale-Software-and-Swiper.html) is one of the PayPal Partner products and it sounds like exactly what you're looking for.